# How to read top 10 headlines from the front page of Reddit using it's API?

Tags: python, api, reddit

I am new to Python and I want to use Reddit API to retrieve top 10 headline on the front page of Reddit using Python. I tried to read the API documentation but I am not able to understand how to proceed.

It would be great if someone can give me an example.

Thanks

Comment: Then we are unable to help you, if you can't even start working on the project.

Comment: Okay I am sorry. www.reddit.com/r/news/top.json?limit=10 Is this the correct URL to get top 10 headlines of the front page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick example on how to download the json data you want.  Basically, open the URL, download the data in JSON format, and use json.loads() to load it into a dictionary.

```
try:
    from urllib.request import urlopen
except ImportError:  # Python 2
    from urllib2 import urlopen

import json

url = 'http://www.reddit.com/r/python/.json?limit=10'
jsonDownload = urlopen(url)
jsonData = json.loads(jsonDownload.read())
```

From there, you can print out 'jsonData', write it to a file, parse it, whatever.